# Sorting and filtering for elements in list for documents containing list

Tags: json, mongodb

## What I want to do:

I would like to output the following expected results of the documents to be processed by the mongoDB command.

(Some documents do not contain arrays).

#### Documents to be processed

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60ddc26b03edfb7a6b424f10"),
    "member": [
        {
            "joinDate": "2021-07-01 12:00:00.000",
            "username": "John"
        },
        {
            "joinDate": "2021-07-01 13:00:00.000",
            "username": "Maria"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-07-01 11:00",
    "roomName": "roomA",
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60ddbcccd495870939756dcb"),
    "member": [
        {
            "joinDate": "2021-07-01 14:00:00.000",
            "userName": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "joinDate": "2021-07-01 11:00:00.000",
            "userName": "George"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-07-01 10:00",
    "roomName": "roomB"
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60ddbcccd495870939756dcc"),
    "createdAt": "2021-07-01 12:00",
    "roomName": "roomC"
}
```

Output results that satisfy the following conditions

- Expand the two elements of the array in the document into the document only for the element with the most recent joinDate.
- Change the element name of the array (add "latest" to the prefix).
- Sort the documents in descending order of the latestJoinDate.
- Do not output documents whose member elements do not exist.

#### Expected result

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60ddbcccd495870939756dcb"),
    "latestJoinDate": "2021-07-01 14:00:00.000",
    "latestUserName": "Jack",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-01 10:00",
    "roomName": "roomB"
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60ddc26b03edfb7a6b424f10"),
    "latestJoinDate": "2021-07-01 13:00:00.000",
    "latestUserName": "Maria",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-01 11:00",
    "roomName": "roomA",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` filter member should exist
- `$sort` by `joinDate` in descending order
- `$max` to get max date from array of `joinDate`
- `$indexOfArray` to select array index of max `joinDate`
- `$arrayElemAt` to select specific object element as per above index
- `$project` to show reauired fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { member: { $exists: true } } },
  { $sort: { "member.joinDate": -1 } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      member: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$member",
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$member.joinDate",
              { $max: "$member.joinDate" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      createdAt: 1,
      roomName: 1,
      latestJoinDate: "$member.joinDate",
      latestUserName: "$member.userName"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cJxvljQSPBi)

Comment: Thank you.

This is almost the answer I was looking for!

However, the following condition was missing, so adding sort at the end made it perfect.

- Sort the documents in descending order of the latestJoinDate.

  {
    $sort: {
      latestJoinDate: -1
    }
  }

Comment: I have updated the answer, You can use `$sort` at the second stage immediately after `$match` stage, whenever it requires indexing, it would be good to use `$match` and `$sort` stage at the top to use the index. if it does in fact answer your question, you can accept by clicking a grey right icon below votes buttons.

Comment: Thank you for additional comments.
Your current answer is perfect.